# chef-server stuck ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep] action run on Docker container

Tags: linux, centos, chef-infra, docker

I have an `ubuntu` host running `docker1.2`. On top of it I have created a `centos6` container which is running great! When I tried to install `chef-server-11.x` version it gets stuck here:

```
  * file[/opt/chef-server/sv/rabbitmq/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/chef-server/init/rabbitmq] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/chef-server/service/rabbitmq] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep] action run
```

After Googling, I found we need to specify platform here in `/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/default.rb`, which I did see following file contains, but it's still not working:

```
when "centos"
  include_recipe "runit::upstart"
```

Do I need to specify something else for docker running `centos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved above issue:

Because Docker replaces the default /sbin/init with its own, there's no way to run the Upstart init inside a Docker container. However this causes some problems: some Debian packages try to communicate with Upstart, and will fail to install.

## Solution:

```
$sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
$sudo ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```