# chef-server stuck ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep] when running reconfigure

Tags: ubuntu, docker, chef-infra

I'm installing an instance of chef-server with this dockerfile (I based it on [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/base/chef-server/~/dockerfile/) file in Docker Hub)

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04


ENV     DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install -yq wget
RUN     wget --content-disposition "https://packages.chef.io/stable/ubuntu/12.04/chef-server_11.1.7-1_amd64.deb"
RUN     dpkg -i chef-server*.deb

RUN    dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
RUN    ln -sv /bin/true /sbin/initctl
COPY   chef-server.rb /etc/opscode/

RUN    chef-server-ctl start

RUN     rm chef-server_11.1.7-1_amd64.deb
ADD     . /usr/local/bin/

EXPOSE  443
```

However, when I run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` i get this

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep]'
```

This is essentially the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614489/chef-server-stuck-ruby-blocksupervise-rabbitmq-sleep-action-run-on-docker-cont) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800653/unable-to-install-chef-server-on-docker-container) post. The first post has a solution, but it doesn't work in my build.

The commands I use to build and run the container are:

```
docker build -t elk/chef-server ~/elk/chef-server/

docker run --name chef-server -h chef-server --net elknet --ip 172.19.2.10 -p 5000:443 -p 5022:22 -t -i -d elk/chef-server /bin/bash
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ doesn't like running in a container. Additionally, Chef Server 11 is long since EOL'd. A better option if you really want to try running Chef Server in Docker would be to start from https://github.com/3ofcoins/docker-chef-server though even that is out of date. As this time we do not recommend running Chef Server inside Docker.